# Method to autofill name/address forms with webdriver (java)

Tags: java, html, xpath, attributes, webdriver

I have to automate forms that ask for standard things like the user's first name, last name, address, etc.

These forms are on websites belonging to various clients, and we have no control over the attributes. The attributes will vary, but there is usually some consistency.

Here's an example. The "first name" text field will usually have an `id` or `name` attribute such as "firstname", "fname", "name1", etc.

```
<input id="firstName" style="width:200px;" value="" type="text">
```

I want to create a method that will recognize "firstName" (and other common form fields, but let's stick to firstname for now)

One way is to have an array of the most likely firstname attributes, something like:

```
 String[] firstNameSelectors = {"firstName", "fname", "name1"};
```

Then I can loop through these, checking them against an xpath such as this:

```
//input[contains(@id, '" + firstNameSelectors[index] + "')]
```

And then I would exit the loop if a match is found.

This would work, to an extend. But here comes a problem. What if it's "firstname" instead of "firstName"? Or "FirstName", or "FIRSTNAME". The xpath won't match because it's case sensitive.

I tried using this xpath to solve the case-sensitivity issue:

```
[contains(translate(@id, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'" 
+ firstNameSelectors[index] + "')]
```

. It works, but I have to specify an attribute—which means I have to do it twice to check both the `id` attribute and the `name` attribute. And if I wanted to check the class, I'd have to do it a third time. And so on.

In short, is there a better way to approach this? Maybe using the javascript executor?

Comment: what's the version of your xpath? I know there is a expression like "//input[lower-case(@id)=yourselector]" if you are in xpath 2. But seems you still need to check every attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure webdriver uses xpath 1

Comment: So that I have no idea. Wait an expert for this.